# MySQL counting by year quarters?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Just a quick question, I know it's possible to count and group by dates although I'm wondering if there is a way for me to do this for year quarters.

With an example table:

```
income_id    |    income_amount   |    income_date
   1                  5.00             2016-01-15
   2                  2.00             2016-02-08
   3                  8.00             2016-04-19
   4                  10.00            2016-09-01
```

Would return similar to:

```
2016 Q1 = 7.00 
2016 Q2 = 8.00
2016 Q3 = 10.00
2016 Q4 = NULL
```

I currently have:

```
SELECT COUNT(income_amount) as total FROM example_table GROUP BY YEAR(income_date), QUARTER(income_date)
```

But I'm getting errors with this?

Comment: And what exactly are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Use `SUM` for summing up your amounts. Here's your query: `SELECT YEAR(income_date) year_, QUARTER(income_date) quarter, SUM(income_amount) as total
    FROM example_table GROUP BY year_, quarter` See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69439/3  You can also put backticks around `year` instead of `year_`

Comment: You probably want `SUM` instead of `COUNT`